# Is this an invalid use of restrict pointers?

Tags: c, c99, restrict-qualifier

Suppose I have large array which I calculate an index into and pass to a second function. As a simple example, something like:

```
void foo(float* array, float c, unsigned int n)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        array[i] *= c;
}

void bar(float* restrict array, float* restrict array2, unsigned int m, unsigned int n)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        foo(&array[i * n], array2[i], n);
}
```

Is this breaking the rules for restrict in bar() where you pass the address of part of the array to foo(), even if you never really use the alias for a part of the array within bar()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(All citations refer to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), which is C99 plus technical corrigenda (TC3).)

The formal definition of `restrict` is given in §6.7.3.1. I quote the most important subclause below. `P` is a `restrict`-qualified pointer to type `T` whose scope is a block `B`. A pointer expression `E` is said to be *based on* `P` if it depends on the value of `P` itself, not the value that `P` points to.

> During each execution of `B`, let `L` be any lvalue that has `&L` based on P. If `L` is used to access the value of the object `X` that it designates, and `X` is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply:
>
> - `T` shall not be const-qualified.
> - Every other lvalue used to access the value of `X` shall also have its address based on `P`.
> - Every access that modifies `X` shall be considered also to modify `P`, for the purposes of this subclause.
> - If `P` is assigned the value of a pointer expression `E` that is based on another restricted pointer object `P2`, associated with block `B2`, then either the execution of `B2` shall begin before the execution of `B`, or the execution of `B2` shall end prior to the assignment.
>
> If these requirements are not met, then the behavior is undefined.

---

Let's look at what the rules have to say about accesses to parts of `bar`'s `array` in `foo`. We start with `array`, a restrict-qualified pointer declared in the parameter list of `bar`. For clarity, I will alpha-convert the parameters of `foo`:

```
void foo(float* b, float c, unsigned int n) { /*modify b[i]*/ }
```

The storage pointed to by `array` is also modified through `b`. That's ok with the second bullet point as `&array[i*n]` is equivalent to `array+(i*n)` (see §6.5.3.2).

*If `b` was restrict-qualified*, then we would have to check the fourth bullet point with `P`​←`b`, `B`​←`foo`, `P2`​←`array`, `B2`​←`bar`. Since `B` is nested inside `B2` (functions behave as if inlined here, see §6.7.3.1.11), the first condition is met. There is also one instanciation of the third bullet point (the access to `b[i]` in `foo`) which is not a problem.

However `b` is not restrict-qualified. According to §6.3.2.3.2, “For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the *q*-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal”. Therefore the conversion from `array+(i*n)` to `b` is well-defined and has the obvious meaning, so the program's behavior is defined. Furthermore, since `b` is not `restrict`-qualified, it doesn't need to obey any linearity condition. For example, the following `foo` is legal in combination with `bar`:

```
void qux(float *v, float *w) {
    v[0] += w[0];
}
void foo(float* b, float c, unsigned int n)
{
    qux(b,b);
}
```

---

**ADDED**: To address your specific concern “in bar() where you pass the address of part of the array to foo()”, this is a non-issue: `restrict` applies to the pointer, not the array, and you can perform arithmetic on it (bullet point 2).

Comment: I can't tell if you're saying it's right or wrong, but props for deploying the standard completely.

Comment: @Matt: The code is correct (in part because the restrict rules aren't doing much here, and in part because you can convert away the restrict qualifier in the subscope delimited by `foo`).

Answer (score -2):

No, restrict means that array can't alias anything, so you can pass stuff to bar without breaking the rules

Comment: I think this question calls for a citation from the standard and not casual explanations along the lines of "restrict means...". C99 aliasing rules are too complicated to rely on casual explanations like that.

Comment: the rules for restrict are pretty simple, it can't be reachable through anything but the restrict pointer.